# Button needs to change status of an object, seems to work in debugging, but nothing happens?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, button, draw

So, I'm making a homework assignment in which I need to build an intersection along with automatic traffic lights, etc. in Windows Form.

Now, for testing purposes I made a button that changes the traffic light status from on to off (or vice-versa). The status is a enum called LampStatus which uses Aan (On), Uit (Off) and Storing (This doesn't need to get used yet).

The lamp class looks like this:

```
public class Lamp
{
    protected Color kleur;
    protected int x, y, straal;
    protected LampStatus status;

    public Color Kleur
    {
        get
        {
            if (status == LampStatus.Uit)
                return Color.Gray;
            else
                return kleur;
        }
        set { kleur = value; }
    }

    public LampStatus Status
    {
        set
        {
            status = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
    }

    // constructor 
    public Lamp()
    {
        kleur = Color.Red;
        x = y = 0;
        straal = 1;
        status = LampStatus.Uit;
    }

    // constructor 
    public Lamp(Color kleur, int x, int y, int r)
    {
        this.kleur = kleur;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.straal = r;
        status = LampStatus.Uit;
    }

    public virtual void Teken(Graphics g)
    {
        if (g != null)
        {
            SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Kleur);
            g.FillEllipse(Brush, x, y, straal, straal);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Black), x, y, straal, straal);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I press the button in Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Lamp lamp = new Lamp(Color.Red, 15, 15, 50);

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        lamp.Teken(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lamp.Status == LampStatus.Uit)
            lamp.Status = LampStatus.Aan;
        else
            lamp.Status = LampStatus.Uit;
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to happen, though when I debug the object lamp, both the color has changed to Color.Red and the status has changed to LampStatus.Aan.

When I hardcode: lamp.Status = LampStatus.Aan in the Form1_Paint method the color does change to red.

Edit; if there is any confusion, just comment and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Add `lamp.Refresh()` at the end of `testButton_Click()`.  Or `this.Invalidate()`.  You need to force it to update.

Comment: What would need to be in the method Refresh()? The this.Invalidate() works by the way. When I have all lamps working, I'll need to invalidate the entire surface every time there is a change?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Did you mean this.Refresh() instead of lamp.Refresh()?

Comment: There is very unhealthy coupling between the class and the form.  You should add a Changed event to the class.  Or derive your class from Control so it can take care of painting itself.

Comment: It was just for testing purpose to see if the lamp would actually be painted properly. Thanks for your comment, though. Got it all working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this.Refresh() fixed the problem and made the lamp color properly change.